# How to authenticate Angular 4 app placed inside ASPNETCORE

Tags: identityserver4

I went through the online samples for IdentityServer4 and I am not able to solve a problem I have.

I have an Angular 4 app placed at the root of an ASP.NET Core 2 app. The ASP.NET Core app has no controllers, only hosting the Angular 4 app. The reason for doing this is to be able to use Hybrid and not Implicit Grant so that tokens are not sent back to Browser.

Now, I could configure the client to be MVC app with HybridAndClientCredentials. But would it work on the Angular side? How to know if the user is authenticated, how to do calls back to API backend, where to get the Access Token in the Angular App, etc. I am kind of confused. I am trying to avoid using the client NPM to integrate with Implicit Flow on Angular because I wanna keep tokens on the server.

Appreciate any feedback.

Thanks

Comment: "But would it work on the Angular side?" think so as long as you make all your calls to the api go via the MVC app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that you are in an impossible situation. According to [OAuth specs](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/which-oauth-flow-to-use) the flow that must be used with SPA'a is Implicit. And also the [IdentityServer specs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/clients.html#defining-browser-based-javascript-client-e-g-spa-for-user-authentication-and-delegated-access-and-api).

If you convert to MVC, you are loosing SPA's functionalities.

Actually the answer is in your question - `where to get the Access Token in the Angular App`. Once you get it in the angular app, it is already exposed to the user. But without having it in the angular app, you can't make the Bearer authentication call.

As I said - impossible situation. If we want to search for something positive here, is that the access token is a short-living token (or at least it is recommended to be so) and after a few minutes it has expired.

PS: In https days, transferring sensitive information "over the cable" is more (I'm not saying bulletproof) secure, and giving the user the access token is like saying him `Hey you have this permissions, your name is <name>` etc. Things that he is supposed to already know.

Comment: Agreed. The "correct" approach for SPAs is basically what the oidc-client-js lib implements. Implicit flow, use access_token to talk to back end stateless API, benefit from automatic token renewal and session monitoring features.
Having the access token exposed to the client is really no more risky than exposing a cookie with the same "permissions" and you also don't have to worry as much about CSRF.